# Word or expression for an opinionated and easily offended person

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology, pejorative-language

Is there a word or expression for someone who uses a lot of opinions to judge himself and/or things around him (such as other people) (e.g. to "defend" himself from receiving judgement), however who is easily offended by someone else based on trivial things they say?

Comment: Pompous ass, perhaps?

Comment: **Entrepreneur**?

Comment: Colloquial expression: *"You can dish it out, but you can't take it."*

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a single word, but an informal American expression would be

> [someone who can dish it out but can’t take it](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/someone-can-dish-it-out-but-he-or-she-can-t-take-it) - someone easily criticizes other people but does not like it when other people criticize him or her

To *[dish out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dish-out)* originates with the sense of serving food to people, but has taken on an idiomatic meaning of meting out severe punishment or criticism. [According to Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=dish), this sense of *dish* dates from 1934. *Taking* criticism, punishment, or abuse is from the sense of [take](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/take) as receiving or accepting, from which the idiom *taking heat* also derives.

While this quality is a [characteristic of narcissists](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/evolution-the-self/201110/the-narcissists-dilemma-they-can-dish-it-out), in lay usage *narcissism* refers mainly to self-absorption or vanity, rather than being simultaneously [hypercritical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hypercritical) and [thin-skinned](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thin-skinned).

Answer (score 8):

Some people would just call the person *sensitive* (or in jest a sensitive Sally).  A common term is *[thin-skinned](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thin-skinned)*.

> easily upset or offended by what other people say about you

When the person gets all upset, they could be called *huffy(-puffy)*.  When a person goes beyond huffy and gets a bit angry then we can use [irascible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/irascible).

> Having or showing a tendency to be easily angered

Comment: Someone who is *sensitive*, *thin-skinned*, *huffy*, or *irascible* isn't necessarily one who has strong opinions or whose criticism of others is unusual in either intensity or frequency. Indeed, *sensitive* can mean quite the opposite.

Comment: @choster - your phrase is great, I was just giving single words.  Everyone can be categorized as thin-skinned or irascible.  The fact is they are comparative words.  Meaning that I probably wouldn't call someone thin-skinned unless they differed from the group norm.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you may be referring to a [presumptuos](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Presumptuous) person :

- characterized by or showing presumption or readiness to presume; unwarrantedly or impertinently bold; forward.

who usually tends to be [touchy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Touchy):

- Tending to take offense with slight cause; oversensitive.

Answer (score 0):

[Prig](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prig) might be appropriate. A priggish person is one who is self-righteous and supercilious.

Further info: [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prig)

Answer (score 0):

I would describe such a person as ***pushy***. Typically, people describe an overly opinionated person as pushy, but don't necessarily imply that the same person is easily offended by others' opinions. However, in my personal experience, overly opinionated, pushy, persons are easily offended by dissenting opinions. You are describing someone that always wants their way and throws a fit when they don't get it. That's pushy.

Answer (score 0):

Try "testy", as in "The testy scholar had managed to offend all his professors."

Comment: A *testy* or *tetchy* person is not necessarily opinionated or judgmental, however.

Answer (score 0):

Pooterish
though, in fact, would also perhaps imply an underlying good humoured nature, a  capacity for self mockery and doleful lament at the ultimate futility of existance

Comment: Please could you provide some references to support these assertions.

Comment: @568ml, see wikipedia ... a *[pooter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooter)* is “a device used in the collection of insects, crustaceans or other small, fragile organisms, usually for scientific purposes”.  Colin may have misread the article, or perhaps misadapted wiktionary's definition of *[Pooterism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pooterism)*, “Taking oneself grotesquely seriously”

Comment: Hello, Colin Thomasson here, in rely to request for reference, Mr Pooter was the celebrated diarist created by the brothers George and Weedon Grossmith in their Victorian comic satire The Diary if a Nobody. George Grossmith was a leading performer in the original productions of several Gilbert and Sullivan comic operas

Answer (score 0):

*opinionated but sensitive* is the best describe in my opinion.