# What's the word for someone who always take things personally?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Like, when you say something objectively and they answer:«I'm not like that, why you say that?». He always suspects what we say got to do something with him! What is it :)?

Comment: He's *insecure*, *defensive*, and *self-absorbed* (because he assumes everything is actually about him. It's not.).

Comment: Related and probable doops: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63852 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68382 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/121348 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/173615 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/244836

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for the unintended offense taken from a comment or compliment?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244836/word-for-the-unintended-offense-taken-from-a-comment-or-compliment)

Answer (score 1):

***hypersensitive*** ([**MW dictionary**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypersensitive))
: having feelings that are very easily hurt

She's hypersensitive about her past.

Comment: Or oversensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the word you are looking for is: -

 **Sensitive**

> Easily upset by the things people say or do...
>   
>  
> e.g. "Her reply showed that she was very sensitive to criticism."
>  
> [ref: Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sensitive)

Comment: If I say "I heard you did really badly in your maths test" and you are upset, that's sensitive. I  say "I heard someone did really badly in their maths test" and you are upset, "sensitive" doesn't feel right.

Comment: True yes I agree. I guess it depends on the meaning of the question, which is a little ambigious. You can say something referring to an individual objectively also.

Answer (score 0):

***[Touchy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/touchy)*** is an adjective commonly used:

> - Tending to take offense with slight cause; oversensitive.

(AHD)
​

> - Easily offended or upset:
>
>   - *You have to be careful what you say to Kevin - he's rather touchy.
>       She's very touchy about the fact that her wife was married before.*

​
(Cambridge Dictionary)